# hibernate - how to persist all entities and subentities at once

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Need help with some Hibernate issues.

1) Want to persist all entities and subentities from one object at once, running the create() method. Is it possible?

2) Having problems with join table. Nothing is persisting in it. I tried to put @ManyToMany mappings to Set collections in `Person` and `Address` classes. Never made it to work and to fill the `PERSON_ADDRESS` table in database.

I have two test methods which I try to run from my test case class. They are all at my [git](https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness/blob/master/src/test/java/me/business/dao/hbn/HbnAddressDaoTest.java). Methods are `testJoinTable()` and `testLoadEverything()`. Please, take a look. Hibernate mappings are in classes from model package.

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID", referencedColumnName = "COUNTRY_ID", insertable = true, nullable = true, unique = false, updatable = true)
    private Country country;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "address" )
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

    @Column(name = "STREET", length = 100)
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "POST_CODE", length = 50)
    private String postCode;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_TYPE", length = 50)
    private String addressType;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false, precision = 20)
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "AddressSeq", sequenceName = "ADDRESS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AddressSeq")
    private Long addressId;

    @Column(name = "CITY", length = 100)
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_ON")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedOn;

    @Column(name = "DISTRICT_NAME", length = 100)
    private String districtName;

    @OneToMany ( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = SomeId.class, mappedBy = "address" )
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<SomeId> someIds;

}
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID", nullable = false, precision = 20)
    @Id
    private Long personId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="PERSON_ADDRESS", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID")})
    private Set<Address> address = new HashSet<Address>();

    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_ON")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedOn;
}
```

Country.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
@NamedQuery(name = "findCountryByCode", query = "from Country where code like :code")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID", nullable = false, precision = 20)
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CountrySeq", sequenceName = "COUNTRY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CountrySeq")
    private Long countryId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Birth.class, mappedBy = "country")
    private Collection<Birth> birthCollection;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "country")
    private Collection<Address> addressCollection;

    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_ON")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedOn;
}
```

SomeId.java

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "SOME_ID" )
public class SomeId {

    @Column( name = "SOME_ID_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 0 )
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "SomeIdSeq", sequenceName = "SOME_ID_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1 )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SomeIdSeq" )
    private Long someIdId;

    @ManyToOne( optional = false, targetEntity = Address.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn( name = "ADDRESS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ADDRESS_ID", insertable = true, nullable = true, unique = false, updatable = true )
    private Address address;

    @Column( name = "CREATED_ON", nullable = false )
    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column( name = "MODIFIED_ON" )
    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date modifiedOn;

    @Column( name = "SOME_ID", nullable = false, length = 100 )
    private String someId;
}
```

To easier get the point what am I trying to accomplish, I'll paste my test methods here:

```
@Test
public void testJoinTable() {
    addressDao.create( address1 );
    addressDao.create( address2 );
    Address address = addressDao.get( address2.getAddressId() );
    assertTrue("address2 don't have 3 persons as expected", address.getPersons().size() == 3);
    long numberOfRecordsInJoinTable = personAddressDao.count();
    assertTrue( "join table PERSON_ADDRESS is not used by Hibernate", numberOfRecordsInJoinTable > 0 );
}

@Test
public void testLoadEverything() {
    address1.setSomeIds( new HashSet<SomeId>() );
    address1.getSomeIds().add( someId1 );
    address1.getSomeIds().add( someId2 );
    addressDao.create( address1 );
    long numberOfRecordsInSomeIdTable = someIdDao.count();
    assertTrue("someIds are not persisted", numberOfRecordsInSomeIdTable > 0);
}
```

Comment: You need to show your entities Person, Address, Country so that we can see annotations or xml.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry, I pasted that git repo link hoping that would be easier to see everything needed to solve my problem. I edited my question with code samples and more information about my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to specify the cascade options on the manytomany from Person > Address:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading